# principal ideal and ideal generated by subset S

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let R be a commutative ring with unity and a in R. Then $<a>$=aR=Ra

We can easily show that aR=Ra, aR ⊆ $<a>$ and Ra ⊆ $<a>$

Next I am trying to show that $<a>$ ⊆ aR

We khow that If S={a} then

$<a>$={na+ra+as+xay|n∈Z and r,s,x,y∈R}

let x ∈ $<a>$ then

x=na+ra+as+xay for some n∈Z and r,s,x,y∈R.

next I want to show that x is also belongs to aR.

But I got stuck.I can workout the part $  ra+as+xay  ∈ aR $ but but I got stuck because of $na$ .I hope someone help me with problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $R$ is a ring with unity, $n$ can be replaced by a sum of $1$s and $-1$s (eg $2 a = a + a = (1 + 1) \cdot a$).

Now say $x=na + ra + as + xay$, by commutativity we get
$$x = na + ra + sa +  xy a = \underbrace{(n + r + s + xy)}_{\in R} a$$

Comment: holly shit..u r smart man.. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user1055704 You are welcome. More formally, there is a unique ring homomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{Z} \mapsto R$ such that $\varphi(1) = 1_R$. By abuse of notation, one writes $n$ for $\varphi(n)$.